# How to get start date and end date of previous month in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, date

I am new in Swift and I am trying to get start date and end date of previous month. I know how to do for current month like this

```
extension Date {
    func startOfMonth() -> Date {
        return Calendar.current.date(from: Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month], from: Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: self)))!
    }
    
    func endOfMonth() -> Date {
        return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(month: 1, day: -1), to: self.startOfMonth())!
    }
    
}
```

But I don't know how to do for previous month. I tried code but not working

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];

NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay) fromDate:currentDate];

components.month = components.month - 1;
components.day = 1;

NSDate *newDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
```

But it is in Objective C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you get current month by current date
then minus 1 to get previous month

```
extension Date {

 func addingRmoving(months: Int) -> Date? {
    let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)

    var components = DateComponents()
    components.calendar = calendar
    components.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
    components.month = months

    return calendar.date(byAdding: components, to: self)
 }


var startOfMonth: Date {

    let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month], from: self)

    return  calendar.date(from: components)!
}


var endOfMonth: Date {
    var components = DateComponents()
    components.month = 1
    components.second = -1
    return Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).date(byAdding: components, to: startOfMonth)!
}



}
```

and how to use it

```
let lastMonth = Date().addingRmoving(months: -1)
let fisrtDayOfLastMonth = lastMonth.startOfMonth
let lastDayOfLastMonth = lastMonth.endOfMonth
```

Comment: Your code works good but I want start date as 1 not 30 or 31.

Comment: it will give you 1 when you convert it in your time zone or run your code on device or check date by converting it string

Comment: simple way is to convert date in string by date formatter

Comment: I used this code let formatterStart = DateFormatter()
        formatterStart.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
        let resultStart = formatterStart.string(from: fisrtDayOfLastMonth!) and it work

Comment: yes it definitely works , as i am already used it in my application that uploaded on appStore ... :)

Answer (score 1):

```
//Mark: - To get last months first day's date
func getLastMonthsFirstDay() -> Date {
let calendar = Calendar.current
let currentDate = Date()
var components = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .month, .day], from: currentDate)
components.month = components.month! - 1
components.day = 1
return  calendar.date(from: components)!
}

//Mark: - To get last months last day's date
func getLastMonthsLastDay() -> Date {
let calendar = Calendar.current
let currentDate = Date()

var components = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .month, .day], from: currentDate)

components.month = components.month! - 1
components.day = -1
return  calendar.date(from: components)!
}
```